# Run asp.net web application on win server 2008

Tags: asp.net, iis

I got a problem when run asp.net web application on windows server 2008

I install dc , dhcp , dns and iis

I try to make a test site to print "hello word " its worked but when i put my asp.net application it gave an error in frame work :

Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework' . note that attribute names are case-sensitive

How to solve it???

Note : i installed framework 4.0 and worked on the same framework in the project

Comment: Did you follow the instructions for installing ASP.NET on Windows Server 2008? Post a link to the instructions you followed.

Comment: http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-iis-7/installing-iis-7-and-above-on-windows-server-2008-or-windows-server-2008-r2

that is the step i follow

Comment: Note that this installs IIS but does not install ASP.NET.

Comment: I notice that and install asp.net

Comment: I made a test .. Folder cotaining default.aspx with hello word its worked well ... Thats mean nothing wrong with asp.net configuration

Comment: (sigh) and what instructions did you follow to install ASP.NET?

Comment: The same as the link above

Comment: No, it means that your test folder does not contain a web.config which has `targetFramework` set incorrectly. I suspect you have ASP.NET 3.5 installed, and you're trying to run a higher version.

Comment: I installed a 4.0 frame work but maybe did not work could u give a complete installation link ??

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install and enable ASP.NET on IIS as well:

http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-iis-7/installing-iis-7-and-above-on-windows-server-2008-or-windows-server-2008-r2

Go down to the section about:

> Figure 3: Select Server Roles
>
> 1. Select the IIS services to be installed on the Select Role Services page. Add only the modules necessary. In this case, ASP.NET is
>      selected, and a description of ASP.NET appears in the right pane. Once
>      desired modules are added, click Next.

By default IIS doesn't have ASP.NET installed (Yeah, weird eh?)

Comment: I am using win server 2008 this configuratiom is for windows

Comment: Updated the link. I would follow the sections listing Figure 3: Select Server Roles

4. Select the IIS services to be installed on the Select Role

Answer (score -1):

you may need to run aspnet_regiis.

[ASP.NET IIS Registration Tool (Aspnet_regiis.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)